# Como mudar o src de uma imagem por responsividade

Tags: javascript, html, image, responsive-design, src

Estou tentando fazer uma troca de imagens quando a tela do navegador tiver abaixo de um mínimo de
pixels

tenho duas imagens e preciso que elas alternem se a tela tiver menos de 600 pixels de comprimento

eu tentei usar js para mudar mas não deu certo

a tag em questão está assim

`<img class="logo" id="logo" src="../img/logoCadjoV.png">`

e o script está assim

```
<script>
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)').matches) {
        var logoImg = document.getElementById('logo');
        if (logoImg) {
            logoImg.src = '../img/logoCadjoH.png'; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

não sei dizer o que está errado, ou se existe um caminho mais fácil

Comment: [English is required for all content on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) You might be interested in [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Your code should be inside a `resize` event listener so it runs whenever the user changes the size of the window. Otherwise it only runs when the page first opens.

Comment: Why not do this with CSS instead of JavaScript? Create two `<img>` elements, and use `@media` in the CSS to change the `display:` styles.